# message sending code working til Android 4.4.4 but not working in lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, sms, message

I made message sending app it work perfect in all version till kitkat  4.4.4  but not working in Lollipop and Marshmallow I don't understand why?

```
public void sendsms()
{

    try 
    {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null,smsmessage, null, null);
        printmsg(1);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        printmsg(0);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void printmsg(int a)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Information:");

    if(a==1)
        builder.setMessage("SMS Send Wait For Response!!!");
    else
        builder.setMessage("Sending Failed, Please Try Again Later!!!");

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "changing activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ResWindow.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            ResWindow.this.finish();

        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are your symptoms? For example, are you crashing? If so, what is your stack trace?

Comment: Add this - Log.i("Message not sent",""); inside the catch block.

Comment: going in else condition "Sending failed Try Again Later" and message is not going and in kitkat working good message sending working and sowing proper message "message sent successfully wait for responce"

Comment: your method is not working @pronoobsanved

Comment: That was just to check if the code goes inside. I think you should send a boolean value to the method first while calling it. Also, Marshmallow needs the user to allow the app to send messages. Maybe it is counterfeiting with it.

Comment: thanks @pronoobsanved my problem solve after giving permission to app from setting->app->myapp->sms 
but i  want to know is there any way user does not need to do this manually

Comment: I have added the answer which will sort this out. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

From API 23, i.e. Android Marshmallow, the app will have to ask for permissions while running instead of declaring them beforehand. The logic here is, to see if the device is below 23, if it is, then the SMS would be sent without any problem, if it 23 and above, you will have to prompt the user to allow the app to send the message.

Here is a sample code with explanation which might help you out there.

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100;

//This is the onClick listener of 'Send SMS' button
public void send(View view) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //This if checks if the device is API 23 or above
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //This checks if the permission is already granted. 
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                //This displays a message to the user as to why do we 
                //need the permission. If the user accepts, we display the permission granting dialog. 
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "You need to grant SEND SMS permission to send sms",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                //This displays the permission granting dialog directly. 
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
        } else {
            sendSMS(); // Runs if the permission is already granted. 
        }
    } else {
        sendSMS(); // Runs if the device's API is below 23. 
    }
}

private void sendSMS() {
    //Code for sending sms. 
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "Permission Granted",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendSMS();
        //SMS sent
    } else {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "Permission denied",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //SMS not sent. 
    }
}
```

The code was taken from [here](http://www.androidrey.com/run-time-permission-request-in-marshmallow/). A more elaborated explanation can be found there.